# Implement JavaScript Int32Array array in Python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to implement something like `Int32Array` in Python. I currently have two problems:

- Convert big numbres to int32
- Take into account little or big encoding

Using Chrome console, I got the following results:

```
var int32 = new Int32Array(2);
int32[0] = 12345678901234567890
Int32Array(2):
    [-350287872, 0]

var int16 = new Int16Array(2);
int16[0] = 12345678901234567890
Int16Array(2):
   [2048, 0]
int16[1] = 12345678901234567890
Int16Array(2):
   [2048, 2048]
```

When I try to convert an big integer using `to_bytes(4)` function, I got an error:

```
>>> (12345678901234567890).to_bytes(4)
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

convert int32 to bytes

```py
offset_int =6422915
offset_bytes = offset_int.to_bytes(4, 'little')
print(offset_bytes)
#return b'\x83\x01b\x00'
```

convert bytes to int32

```py
# declaring byte value
byte_val = b'\x83\x01b\x00'

# converting to int
# byteorder is big where MSB is at start
int_val = int.from_bytes(byte_val, "little")
print(int_val)
# return 6422915
```

if you want Int16 to bytes

```
offset_int =65535
offset_bytes = offset_int.to_bytes(2, 'little')
print(offset_bytes)
#return b'\xff\xff'
```